# Passing vectors of different types to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am getting a compiler error that says

`could not deduce template argument for 'std::vector<T*>&' from 'std::vector<_Ty>'`

```
template <typename T> void foo(vector<T*>& a, int left, int right)
{
     ...
}

main()
{
     ...
     //declare and instantiate 3 vectors
     vector<int> intVector;

     foo(intVector, 0, 100);
     foo(doubleVector, 0, 100);
     foo(charVector, 0, 100);
     ...
}
```

Comment: `vector<T*>&` means you want a vector of pointers and you're giving it a vector of non-pointers.

Comment: Why are you doing `vector<T*>` and not just `vector<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

`int` cannot match `T*`.

Either make the `vector` a `vector<int*>` or make the template take `vector<T>`.